# Composite Key with two many-to-one keys in Hibernate

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, hibernate, dictionary

I got 3 classes.
Class 1+2 are just empty classes with ids.

Class 3 has 2 attributes:

```
private long id;  <---- DO I NEED THIS???  
private Class1 abc;  
private Class2 cde;
```

Those are both many-to-one and should define the key of this class together e.g.
There are no 2 class3 instances where abc=abc AND cde=cde.
I tried it like this:

```
<composite-id name="id" class="class3">     
    <key-property name="abc" column="ID_CLASS1"/>
    <key-property name="cde" column="ID_CLASS2" />          
</composite-id>
```

This does not reflect the many-to-one relationship AND it doesn't compile!

Could someone post a mapping that would work in my special case? 
I read all the documentation but can't just not figure it out!
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

So, you have two tablew A and B, and a join table between A and B. You thus probably have a ManyToMany association between A and B. You should thus not have an ID in this table, and you should not map it as an entity.

Use a ManyToMany association, as explained in [the reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#collections-bidirectional).

Comment: Yes you could view class3 as a join table! Still class3 needs to exist as it is and I cant use a many-to-many because the relationship is not stored in class1 or class2. The problem is that you have to define the many-to-many relation "from the inside out"! so in the mapping file of class3

Comment: Then keep the numeric ID column in the table, and map this table as an entity with an autogenerated ID and two unidirectional ManyToOne associations. Don't use composite IDs.

Comment: Just had a 2. thought. Then the information is lost that There are no 2 class3 instances where abc=abc AND cde=cde

Comment: Now I thought about it so I have a one-to-one relationship between class1 and class2 this relationship is mapped in class3. For that class3 has 2 Objects of type class1 and type class2. Now these two objects identify the certain instance of class3. What you posted is a workaround but I cant understand why its not just working with a composite-id!